# Suppose $\phi:K[x]\to K[x]$ is an automorphism such that $\phi(u)=u\ \forall u\in K$. Prove that $\phi(x)=ax+b$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $K$ be a field. Suppose $\phi:K[x]\to K[x]$ is an automorphism such that $\phi(u)=u\ \forall u\in K$. Prove that $\phi(x)=ax+b$.

Since $K$ is  a field then $K[x]$ is an Euclidean Domain.What to do next?

Comment: Think about degrees. What degree polynomial can $x$ be mapped to?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi (x) = f = \sum \limits _{k=0} ^m f_k x^k$ with $f_m \ne 0$. Since $\phi$ is surjective, there exist $g = \sum \limits _{k=0} ^n g_k x^k$ with $g_n \ne 0$ such that $\phi (g) = x$. Developing this we get $x = \sum \limits _{k=0} ^n g_k f^k = \sum \limits _{k=0} ^n g_k (\sum \limits _{i=0} ^m f_i x^i)^k = g_n (f_m)^n x^{mn} + \dots$ (this being the largest term). Equating the degrees on both sides of the equality gives $mn = 1$ and since $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers, the only possibility is $m=1$ and $n=1$, therefore $\phi(x)$ has degree $1$ as stated.

Where have we used that $K$ is a field (and not an arbitrary ring)? When we silently assumed that $g_n (f_m)^n \ne 0$; since $f_m \ne 0$ and $g_n \ne 0$ then this is true not only in fields, but in fact in integral domains, so the assumption of the problem can be relaxed a little bit.